# jxls transformation creates error in defined named ranges

Tags: java, excel, transformation, jxls

I have an excel template as follows

First Sheet is Named **State** it has the following data

```
Cell A1 --> State
Cell B1 --> Count
Cell A2 --> B4 
<jx:forEach items="${stateList}" var="row"> 
${row[0]}    ${row[1]} 
</jx:forEach>
```

I have a named Range StateNames defined as =OFFSET(State!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(State!$A$2:State!$A$100),1), which is suppose to evaluate to A2 --> Last Filled values, so if there were 20 states then it will evaluate to A2-->A21

The problem is that after the transformation, the Named Range Contains
=OFFSET(State!#REF!,0,0,COUNTA(State!#REF!:State!$A$100),1)

The reason based on my research seems to be that since A2 cell got transformed into A2:A21 the named range is trying to replace State!$A$2 with the State!$A$2:$A$21 and which caused the problem since the OFFSET function is not expecting a range.

I need help to figure out how to solve the issue. I need the named ranges to later use in the Charts. But the basic problem is how to make sure that the named ranges refer to the correct locations.

Thanks